# CXF using FIQL, null SearchBean

Tags: java, cxf

I tried a very simple first step into FIQL with CXF with following code:

```
SearchCondition<SearchBean> searchCondition = searchContext.getCondition(SearchBean.class);
SearchBean searchBean = searchCondition.getCondition();
```

When called with `"_s=foo==test"` I get a `searchBean` but when called with `"_s=foo==test;bar==test"` the `searchBean` is `null`

What do I do wrong?

(addtional information: CXF version is 2.7.17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker found the solution in case someone is in the same situation:

When one condition `condition.getCondition()` works and `condition.getConditions()` is null but when several conditions are matched, `condition.getConditions()` works (returns a `List<SearchCondtion>`) and `condition.getCondition()` is null